# Reset(not removing) property for duplicates in a list using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class `AttachDoc` with property: `DOCUMENT_ID, DOC_NAME`
The list is populated with duplicates
Ex:

```
1   Name1
2   Name2
2   Name2
3   Name3
```

The second Name2 is a duplicate (based on id and name) and I wanna reset its name, but keeping that row. The expected outcome is:

```
1  Name1
2  Name2
2  null
3  Name3
```

How could I manage it using LINQ? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming data:

```
List<AttachDoc> list = new List<AttachDoc>()
{
    new AttachDoc(){ Id = 1, Name = "Name1" },
    new AttachDoc(){ Id = 2, Name = "Name2" },
    new AttachDoc(){ Id = 2, Name = "Name2" },
    new AttachDoc(){ Id = 3, Name = "Name3" },
};
```

you can use `GroupBy`, which produces desired results:

```
var desiredValue = "Desired value";
var groups = list.GroupBy(x => x.Id + x.Name,
                            (key, elements) =>
                                elements.Select((y, index) => 
                                    new AttachDoc() 
                                    { 
                                        Id = y.Id, 
                                        Name = index > 0 ? desiredValue  : y.Name 
                                    }))
                    .SelectMany(x => x);
```

Comment: @AnOverflowedStack are you `using System.Linq`?

Comment: Thank you very much. Fully tested. Working!

Answer (score 1):

It's result:

```
public class Names
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Names() { }
    public static List<Names> SampleData()
    {
        return new List<Names>()
        {
                new Names(){ Id = 1, Name = "Name1" },
                new Names(){ Id = 2, Name = "Name2" },
                new Names(){ Id = 2, Name = "Name2" },
                new Names(){ Id = 3, Name = "Name3" },
        };
    }
}
```

and Main function:

```
var query = (from element in names
                        group element by new { element.Id, element.Name } into g
                        select new
                        {
                            Id = g.Key.Id,
                            Name = g.Key.Name,
                            Count = g.Count()
                        }).Where(p=>p.Count > 1).ToList();

            List<int> idToChange = new List<int>();
            for (int i=0; i < names.Count; i++)
            {

                if (query.Select(p => p.Id).Contains(names[i].Id))
                {
                    if (idToChange.Contains(names[i].Id))
                        names[i].Name = "null";
                    else
                        idToChange.Add(names[i].Id);
                }
            }
```

and the final result - list names contain:

```
1.Name1
2.Name2
2.null
3.Name3
```